# Telecommunications Spending Data for Businesses

Tags: data-request, business, telecom

I wasn't 100% sure if this was the right community to ask this in, this community was recommended to me.
 Is there a database or source where I can find how much businesses spend on their Telecommunications budget. I work for a Telecom company and am trying to do data analysis for network planning. I apologize if this isn't the right location. We have previously used Equifax but each report from them is very expensive.

Comment: Is there another group thst may be better for this question?